# How can I follow a particular CPAN module's updates?

Tags: perl, cpan

I subscribe to the CPAN weekly update mailing list but it reports on every module updated in the past week.

Instead, I would like to subscribe to particular modules and get only their updates. I want to "follow" that module for the purposes of reviewing interesting fixes/enhancements and choosing when I want to upgrade.

The mailing list is too much info to wade through.

How can I follow/subscribe to a particular CPAN module's updates?

Comment: I just opened a ticket to ask this feature from the http://metacpan.org/ folks. I think you could easily use their API for specific modules.

Answer (score 6):

Write a Perl script to do it!

Schedule the script to parse the [CPAN Changes Feed](http://changes.cpanhq.org/recent/feed) daily and then have the script mail you the details of any changes to the modules you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of this and was hoping it was done already :D Last time I went into XML it was very involved.

Answer (score 3):

I found about [CPAN-Outdated](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanoutdated/bin/cpan-outdated) just the other day.

Comment: Combine that with [cpan-listchanges](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/cpan-listchanges-0.05/bin/cpan-listchanges) and you get a list of changelog for outdated modules that needs updating.